# function creating summation of count rather than starting over at 0

Tags: dataframe, list, dictionary, count

I'm iterating through a data set. The data set is a list of dictionaries. The values in the dictionaries include lists. I am trying to create a function that counts all of the big and small equipment in those values.

I've created empty dictionaries for my function to count to, but it is doing one of two things. Either 1) it is summing each dictionary together or 2) spitting out a list of tuppled dictionaries that are not counting occurrences.

```
#create equipment lists for big and small items
#first create the items that we define as large equipment
big_equip = ['pot', 'skillet', 'sheet pan']
#then using that list generate a list of big equipment from Sanity's full equipment list
big_equipment = [bigE for bigE in equipment_list if any(xs in bigE for xs in big_equip)]


#second create the items that we define as small equipment
sml_equip = ['Whisk', 'Wooden spoon', 'Tongs', 'Spatula', 'bowl']
#then using that list generate a list of big equipment from Sanity's full equipment list
small_equipment = [smallE for smallE in equipment_list if any(xs in smallE for xs in sml_equip)]


def count_equipment(recipe):
    x = {'big equipment':0}
    y = {'small equipment':0}
    for z in recipe['equipment']:
        if z in big_equipment:
            x['big equipment'] += 1
        if z in small_equipment:
            y['small equipment'] += 1
        return x,y

equipment_columns = [count_equipment(_) for _ in safe_result]
```

Comment: why is `return x,y` inside the loop?

Comment: When I don't have return, I get 'None'. But maybe I'm putting it in the wrong spot?

Comment: Yes, you have one indent too much, since now the for loop will never complete. After the first iteration, it reaches the return statement and the function returns, without completing the loop. You only want to return after the loop has been completed, aka outside the loop.

Comment: Please also provide a minimalistic, but ready to use example. How does `safe_result` look like? How do the lists (?) `small_equipment` and `big_equipment` look like? And what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a list of recipes, and you want to count how much equipment belongs in which category. In that case, you want a global count of big and small equipments, so initialising the dictionaries again each time you call `count_equipment` and returning those dictionaries, will give you a list of tuples, containing these 2 dictionaries with the result of each recipe seperately, but not added together. So you want those variables to be independent of the function, like this:

```
x = {'big equipment':0}
y = {'small equipment':0}

def count_equipment(recipe):
    for z in recipe['equipment']:
        if z in big_equipment:
            x['big equipment'] += 1
        if z in small_equipment:
            y['small equipment'] += 1
    return x,y

equipment_columns = [count_equipment(_) for _ in safe_result]
```

which will count together the equipment from all your recipes. At this point, you don't need to return anything anymore. Furthermore, since `x` and `y` will hold the info you need, also the `equipment_columns` is rather useless at this point. And it would make sense to have one dictionary for both counts, since your dictionaires only hold one variable, like so:

```
equipment_count = {'big equipment':0, 'small equipment':0}

def count_equipment(recipe):
    for z in recipe['equipment']:
        if z in big_equipment:
            equipment_count['big equipment'] += 1
        if z in small_equipment:
            equipment_count['small equipment'] += 1

for _ in safe_result:
    count_equipment(_)

print(equipment_count)
```

If you then want to only count unique equipment for all recipes, you need to track the equipment and add it to a list:

```
equipment_count = {'big equipment':[], 'small equipment':[]}

def count_equipment(recipe):
    for z in recipe['equipment']:
        if z in big_equipment and z not in equipment_count['big equipment']:
            equipment_count['big equipment'].append(z)
        if z in small_equipment and z not in equipment_count['small equipment']:
            equipment_count['small equipment'].append(z)

for _ in safe_result:
    count_equipment(_)

for key in equipment_count:
    equipment_count[key] = len(equipment_count[key])

print(equipment_count)
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

After clarification, you want this:

```
def count_equipment(recipe):
    equipment_count = {'big equipment':0, 'small equipment':0}

    for z in recipe['equipment']:
        if z in big_equipment:
            equipment_count['big equipment'] += 1
        if z in small_equipment:
            equipment_count['small equipment'] += 1

    return equipment_count

for recipe in safe_result:
    recipe.update(count_equipment(recipe))
```

The function counts the equipment class and returns (outside of the for loop, to make sure the loop completes) a dictionary containing the counts of both equipments. Then, the `update` method of `dict` will take all the keys of the returned dictionary and adds them to the original, so now you have a list of recipes, in which the 'columns' with the counts are added. Because you only have one dictionary, instead of 2 variables you returned as a tuple, you can use the update method. Otherwise, when returning `x,y`, you would need to expand that tuple and then add the entries individually to the recipe again, which is a bit untidier, like so

```
def count_equipment(recipe):
    x = {'big equipment':0}
    y = {'small equipment':0}
    for z in recipe['equipment']:
        if z in big_equipment:
            x['big equipment'] += 1
        if z in small_equipment:
            y['small equipment'] += 1
    return x,y

for recipe in safe_result:
    big, small = count_equipment(recipe)
    recipe['big'] = big['big equipment']
    recipe['small'] = small['small equipment']
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your response. It's so appreciated. You're really close to what I'm trying to figure out. I'm ultimately trying to get a count of equipment for each recipe individually and then add that as a column (another key, value pair in each recipe's dictionary). The idea is: how many things that qualify as big equipment are in this recipe, and how many things that qualify as small?

Comment: Updated the answer with the new infos, I think this is what you wanted, right?

Comment: You're welcome :) If it solved your problem, please mark the question as solved by accepting the answer